# Using Page keyword in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it necessary to use the Page keyword in asp.net? For example, are there differences setting the Title or control if the page IsPostBack?

If we don't use the Page keyword will there be a problem in the future?

Because the code appears to do the same thing:

```
Page.Title = "Test";
```

is equal to

```
Title = "Test";
```

Comment: Not sure I follow...  What do you mean by controlling IsPostBack without using Page?

Comment: I mean using Page.Title to set the title or using just Title to set the title.

Comment: Huh? Do you need to use a *Page* to control whether a *Page* is posted back? Did you think this through?...

Comment: the code file is inheriting from "Page" which is why you can access "Title" directly.

Comment: I was using Page. for Title, IsPostBack, MetaKeywords, MetaDescription etc. always before...

Comment: your right, it's the same thing, doesn't matter which one you use, wont cause any side affects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET pages and controls ultimately inherit from `Control`, which has a property named `Page`, which refers to the current page the control is on, or, in the case of pages, the page themselves. As far as I know, there's no difference between calling `Page.Title` and `Title` from your pages, because they both refer to the same object. The question then, becomes a matter of preference and convention. I would pick one way and stick with it for readability.

**Reference:**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx

Comment: within an instanced method (i.e. Page_Load) the 'this' keyword will also reference the Page so this.Title = Page.Title = Title